# Problems parsing CSV file row into Object Graph

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

here's what my csv file looks like:

```
1,couchName1,“green”,“suede”
2,couchName2,“blue”,“suede”
3,couchName3,fail,“sued”
...etc.
```

I need to read this csv and convert each row into a couch object graph.  So here is what I tried:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCsvFile(string filePath)
    {
        IEnumerable<string[]> file = File.ReadLines(filePath).Select(a => a.Split(';'));
        return file;
    }


public static List<Couch> GetCouches(string csvFilePath)
{
    IEnumerable<string[]> fileRows = FileUtilities.ReadCsvFile(csvFilePath);

    if (fileRows == null) return new List<Couch>(); 
    int couchId;

    List<Couch> couches = fileRows.Select(row => new Couch
     {  
        CouchId = int.TryParse(row[0],  out couchId) ? couchId : 0,
        Name= row[1],
        Color= row[2],
        Fabric= row[3]
       }).ToList();

    return couches;
}
```

I get the error {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."} on the line with the LINQ select statement where I'm trying to parse them into my Couch instances and into a generic list that I want to return them by.

**SOLUTION:**

Here's how I got it working, solved it myself:

```
public static List<Couch> GetCouches(string csvFilePath)
{
    IEnumerable<string[]> fileRows = FileUtilities.ReadCsvFile(csvFilePath);
    List<Couch> couches = new List<Couch>(); // ADDED THIS

    if (fileRows == null) return new List<Couch>(); 
    int couchId;

    // NEW LOGIC, SPLIT OUT EACH ROW'S COLUMNS AND THEN MAKE THE OBJECT GRAPH
    foreach(string[] row in fileRows)
    {
        string[] rowColumnValues = row[0].Split(',').ToArray();

        couches.Add(new Couch
                            {
                              CouchId = int.TryParse(rowColumnValues[0],  out couchId) ? couchId : 0,
                              Name= rowColumnValues[1],
                              Color= rowColumnValues[2],
                              Fabric= rowColumnValues[3]
    }

    return couches;
}
```

Comment: does every row in your csv file contain those 4 values?  have you confirmed?  all it takes is one row having less values...

Comment: yes it does..they all have 4 values per row but I'm wondering if all 4 values need to be surrounded by quotes to make it a string...

Comment: Can you post the code for that `ReadCsvFile` method? If the data is correct then that would be a good place to check.

Comment: @nick, posted the readcsv method.  This is for a test, all I want to do is to push that into an object graph.  I think the Name might need quotes around it in the csv just like the color and fabric as they are descriptions but the actual ID is numeric.  So I'm not sure if I have my csv file formatted right either...in terms of the quotes and such with the comma delimited values.  I may have a parsing issue also due to the csv format?  or that I again need to take each row & split out to another array then make the object graph on the row's column array basically which is what I may be missing?

Comment: It looks like you are splitting on the `;` character - try `,`.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could think of would be that some rows in fileRows may not have the expected four elements.

Comment: no actually I think what I'm doing wrong is I need to take each row and split that into a seperate array itself where I took the comma delimited values and parsed it into its own array of values then try to object graph off that.  Right now it's doing something like this Color = 1,couchName1,“green”,“suede” instead of Color = column[3]  so it's like I need a column array for each row and parse it down to the column level...not sure.

Comment: It looks like the lines may not have split the way you wanted them to. Looking at the ReadCsvFile code you posted, it looks like you're splitting using ';' as the separator while your actual data is using ','.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.  I needed to split the rows into columns.

See my latest update above.